# What is the cypher query for one node but not another?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that looks like this -

```
customer-hasOrder->order
order-hasLineItem->orderLineItem
orderLineItem-hasService->service
orderLineItem-providedOn->providedOnDate
orderLineItem-providedBy->vendor
```

I need to determine if a particular service, say a service named "A" was provided to some customer on some date without another service, say a service named "B", also being provided on that same date by the same vendor. This should be true no matter how many orders were submitted by a customer on a given day. In other words, service "A" should always be provided on the same day as service "B" by the same vendor any time a customer orders "A."

Here is what I have to find customers that had "A" but not "B" on the same day -

```
START  
    s1 = node:service(id="A"),
    s2 = node:service(id = "B"),
MATCH
    customer-[:hasOrder]->(o1)-[:hasLineItem]->li1-[:hasService]->s1,
    customer-[:hasOrder]->(o2)-[:hasLineItem]->li2-[r?:hasService]->s2,
    ol1-[:providedBy]->p1,
    ol2-[:providedBy]->p2,
    ol1-[:providedOn]->d1,
    ol2-[:providedOn]->d2
WHERE
    d1 = d2 AND p1 = p2 AND r is null
    RETURN customer
```

I decided to come here after my nose started bleeding trying to figure out the Cypher query for this.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at it from a different angle, aggregating on the relevant nodes (customer,provider,date)

```
START  
    service = node:service("id:(A B)"),
MATCH
    customer-[:hasOrder]->(order)-[:hasLineItem]->item-[:hasService]->service,
    item-[:providedBy]->provider,
    item-[:providedOn]->date
WITH
    customer,provider,date,count(distinct service) as service_count
WHERE
    service_count = 1
RETURN customer,provider,date
```

You could also look into path expressions to check if another line-item exists for the same provider and date but NOT the service B.

```
START  
    s1 = node:service(id="A"),
    s2 = node:service(id="B"),
MATCH
    customer-[:hasOrder]->(o1)-[:hasLineItem]->li1-[:hasService]->s1,
    customer-[:hasOrder]->(o2)-[:hasLineItem]->li2
    li1-[:providedBy]->provider,
    li2-[:providedBy]->provider,
    li1-[:providedOn]->date,
    li2-[:providedOn]->date
WHERE
    NOT (li2-[:hasService]->s2)

RETURN customer
```